# Restrict shell commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rsync

I created a username with the bash shell — a normal shell with all commands available — but I intend to use this shell for a backup service, which should allow only the `rsync` command. Therefore, I am trying to restrict this shell to execute `rsync` commands only. How can I do this with `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`?

Additional Information: This shell is used to back up files and folders only. I connect another shell to `rsync` using an `ssh` key.

Comment: how is the shell being accessed? If it is via ssh, for example, you can set up using an `authorized_keys` file.

Comment: could i restrict the command via authorized_keys ? if so then how could this be done to restrict all command except rsync command ?

Comment: If you go the authorized keys route, be sure to change the ownership on **$HOME**, **$HOME/.ssh** and the authorized_keys file itself so that the user can't change authorized_keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't - not using just those files.  Why not give them another shell, with fewer options?
[rssh](http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/) is designed for just this purpose.

Advantages of rssh over authorized_keys restrictions (not all may apply to you or be interesting):

- Can be used to control more than one user
- Restriction is applied from without rather than from within the user's personal config - less chance of a mistake allowing them greater access
- Makes chrooting user easier
- rssh is not a general purpose shell, so even if misconfigured, the scope offered to the user is much less than if bash + authorized_keys is misconfigured.

Comment: but rssh is a restricted shellallowing only scp and/or sftp they not good as rsync command unfortunately

Comment: rssh explicitly **does** allow rsync.  Read the second line on the link I gave you.

Comment: can i restrict the commands through authorized_keys files ? or this cannot be done too ?

Comment: i used rssh and everything is perfect now with rsync , thanks for help